# font - Arial to Georgia, reading with more comfortability

Tags: feature-request, design

I don't know if its true, but i'm sure people would like it to read questions, answers and other main text that are in the *Georgia* font instead of the current *Arial*. What's the difference?

As you see, the text block on the top is *Arial*, the text block on the bottom is in *Georgia*. I think its a little change but for me it **reads faster** and give me a better user-experience. This font is also applied on Math.SE.

What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Currently your only option if you want different fonts is to write or copy a user script that does it.

There is definitely no way SE will do this, they have actually rationalised designs and fonts across all the sites to avoid differences.

One a personal note, in my opinion your font choice makes things harder to read for me.

Comment: Absolutely, its a worse font IMO. There are other fonts that are better than Arial, if we were to have that option - but we don't. (Btw though there are other fonts I prefer - there are very good reasons to go with Arial anyway, including ubiquity and commonness. )